# Modelica annotation Window

Tags: annotations, modelica

What does the Modelica `annotation(Window())` do and where does it come from?
Here is an example:

```
annotation (
    Window(
      x=0.15,
      y=0.16,
      width=0.63,
      height=0.59));
```

It is not described in the Modelica Specification and when checking with Dymola 2015 and `Advanced.PedanticModelica=true` I get an error.
Can I safely delete the annotation? Where did it come from?

Comment: related: Advanced.EnableAnnotationCheck https://stackoverflow.com/a/59026735/874701

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are old Dymola annotations that can be safely removed (ttws -clean does this actually)